# how to get 2-d hash as an output from hstore column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hash, hstore

In rails app I try to store 2-d hash in postgreSql hstore column, but for output I get something like

> {"6/5"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}", "8/1"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}", "8/2"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}", "8/3"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}"}.

How can I get 2-d hash as output or maybe you can give some advice for how to parse it?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to convert this into hash here is how you could it do:

```
str = {"6/5"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}", "8/1"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}", "8/2"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}", "8/3"=>"{\"color\"=>\"white\"}"}
p str.each_with_object({}){|(k,v),h| h[k] = eval(v)}
```

Result

> {"6/5"=>{"color"=>"white"}, "8/1"=>{"color"=>"white"}, "8/2"=>{"color"=>"white"}, "8/3"=>{"color"=>"white"}}

Comment: This works nice, but I'm wondering if this should be not a function of the hstore gem to return it always back as a hash.

Answer (score 0):

To store a hash in sql database, you can use a string column and add this line to the model:

```
serialize :my_hash_thingy
```

It should handle every serialization / deserialization in the background, and you will have tha hash normally every time you use it.

Comment: In my model I have 
serialize :checkers, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore. 

checkers is of type hstore(postgreSQL)

Comment: @AndreyYasinishyn me I have the same problemn. The 2nd level is given back as string an I can not navigate in it because it isn't a hash anymore. I have also serialize :fied_name, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore in my model and my field is a hstore for postgresql

Comment: The documentation says "This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs". So I think it is impossible to store multidimentional hashes in it. But in other hand I was confused by this line in documentation "%# hstore    convert hstore to two-dimensional key/value array    %# 'a=>foo, b=>bar'::hstore   {{a,foo},{b,bar}}". But I don't quite know how to use it in rails 3.2.11.